# Can not save policy disableServiceAccountKeyCreation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am Super Admin in my google organisation and trying to change googles default policies.
Actually the only thing I want to enable is `iam-disableServiceAccountKeyCreation` so I can create a key for my service account.

First I was not even able to access the edit view for iam-disableServiceAccountKeyCreation, needed to change some roles to access that ( I am super admin??)

After changing iam-disableServiceAccountKeyCreation to `Customize` and setting rule as `not enforced` clicking save gives me an error. There is no indicator what to do, also I am not able to find any help online.

[image]

Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Super Admin is a Google Workspace permission. Which Cloud IAM roles do you have in Google Cloud? You need a role like Org Policy Admin: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints#required-roles

Answer (score 0):

You must have required roles to modify [organization policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/Policy) to set constraints. The [orgpolicy.policyAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org) role has permission to set organization policy constraints.

You can use the `iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation` boolean constraint to disable the creation of new external service account keys which allows you to control the use of unmanaged long-term credentials for service accounts. When this constraint is set, user-managed credentials cannot be created for service accounts in projects affected by the constraint.

After setting the orgpolicy admin role, set the organization policy that enforces a constraint to enable the creation of service account keys by following this [document.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts#setting_a_boolean_constraint)

Answer (score 0):

To turn off enforcement of the disableServiceAccountKeyCreation policy, you need to make sure your IAM user at the organization level (not the project level) has the correct access (Roles as Organization Administrator, Organization Policy Administrator, Owner).

Then you can modify disableServiceAccountKeyCreation in the 'Organization Policies' section (also at the organization level).

Once you do this, when you go back to the project level and look at the disableServiceAccountKeyCreation policy in 'Organization Policies' there, you will see that it has inherited and reflects your new setting